# How to hide a id column from displaying in jqGrid table?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Here is my code, please help me hide the `id` column in jqGrid, I am assuming in order to select current row i will be needing this `id` column but dont want it to be flashing in my table

[image]

**Updated with ospatches**

```
var ospatches=[];

$(xml).find('patch').each(function(){ 
    var row={};
    row.name=$(this).attr('name');
    ospatches.push(row);
});


$('#detailTable').empty();
$('<div width="100%">')
.attr('id','ospatchesSpan')
.html('<div class="titleBlue">Configuration&gt;System&gt;Os Patches</div>'+
        '<table id="list1" width="100%"></table>'+
        '<div id="gridpager"></div>'+
    '</div>')        
.appendTo('#detailTable');    



jQuery("#list1").jqGrid({
    datatype: "clientSide",
    height: 250,
       colNames:['Name'],
       colModel:[
           {name:'name',index:'name', align:"right"},

       ],
       pagination:true,
       pager : '#gridpager',
       rowNum:10,
       scrollOffset:0,
       height: 'auto',
       autowidth:true,
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    edit:false,
    add:false,
    del:false

});



for(var i=0;i<ospatches.length;i++)
    jQuery("#list1").jqGrid('addRowData',i+1,ospatches[i]);

jQuery("#list1").setGridParam({rowNum:10}).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

Here is my data that takes too long.. i am posting only half of it, same location as `filesystem`

```
<ospatches>
<patch name='gnome-kerberos-0.3.3-1' />
<patch name='cdecl-2.5-30' />
<patch name='sr_mod-Dell_RHEL4a-4dkms' />
<patch name='gsk7bas-7.0-3.18' />
<patch name='pdksh-5.2.14-30.3' />
<patch name='IBM_db2chen81-8.1.3-136' />
<patch name='IBM_db2icms81-8.1.3-136' />
<patch name='perl-String-CRC32-1.4-2.fc6' />
<patch name='nc-1.84-10.fc6' />
<patch name='libdv-0.104-4.fc6.1' />
<patch name='specspo-13-1.el5' />
<patch name='system-config-services-0.9.4-1.el5' />
<patch name='rp-pppoe-3.5-32.1' />
<patch name='cyrus-sasl-2.1.22-4' />
<patch name='xmlsec1-1.2.9-8.1' />
<patch name='libXvMC-1.0.2-2.1' />
<patch name='automake15-1.5-16' />
<patch name='swig-1.3.29-2.el5' />
<patch name='automake-1.9.6-2.1' />
<patch name='curl-devel-7.15.5-2.el5' />
<patch name='cvs-1.11.22-5.el5' />
<patch name='xorg-x11-fonts-misc-7.1-2.1.el5' />
<patch name='xorg-x11-drv-tek4957-1.1.0-1.1' />
<patch name='gtk+-1.2.10-56.el5' />
<patch name='xorg-x11-resutils-7.1-2.fc6' />
<patch name='scim-qtimm-0.9.4-5' />
<patch name='kde-i18n-French-3.5.4-1' />
<patch name='setup-2.5.58-4.el5' />
<patch name='words-3.0-9.1' />
<patch name='bash-3.2-24.el5' />
<patch name='libICE-1.0.1-2.1' />
<patch name='libgpg-error-1.4-2' />
<patch name='pkgconfig-0.21-2.el5' />
<patch name='slang-2.0.6-4.el5' />
<patch name='libogg-1.1.3-3.el5' />
<patch name='desktop-file-utils-0.10-7' />
<patch name='ORBit2-2.14.3-5.el5' />
<patch name='flac-1.1.2-28.el5_0.1' />
<patch name='crash-4.0-7.2.3' />
<patch name='traceroute-2.0.1-5.el5' />
<patch name='libvorbis-1.1.2-3.el5_1.2' />
<patch name='libidn-0.6.5-1.1' />
<patch name='libXinerama-1.0.1-2.1' />
<patch name='libXfontcache-1.0.2-3.1' />
<patch name='perl-libwww-perl-5.805-1.1.1' />
<patch name='startup-notification-0.8-4.1' />
<patch name='e2fsprogs-libs-1.39-20.el5' />
<patch name='module-init-tools-3.3-0.pre3.1.42.el5' />
<patch name='dmraid-1.0.0.rc13-33.el5' />
<patch name='m2crypto-0.16-6.el5.3' />
<patch name='nss_ldap-253-17.el5' />
<patch name='pycairo-1.2.0-1.1' />
<patch name='xorg-x11-xinit-1.0.2-15.el5' />
<patch name='newt-0.52.2-12.el5' />
<patch name='util-linux-2.13-0.50.el5' />
<patch name='gtk2-2.10.4-20.el5' />
<patch name='fipscheck-1.0.3-1.el5' />
<patch name='smartmontools-5.38-2.el5' />
<patch name='dbus-glib-0.73-8.el5' />
<patch name='kudzu-1.2.57.1.21-1' />
<patch name='pciutils-devel-2.2.3-5' />
<patch name='strace-4.5.18-2.el5' />
<patch name='perl-IO-Socket-INET6-2.51-2.fc6' />
<patch name='mysql-5.0.45-7.el5' />
<patch name='php-ldap-5.1.6-23.el5' />
<patch name='perl-IO-Socket-SSL-1.01-1.fc6' />
<patch name='redhat-artwork-5.0.9-1.el5' />
<patch name='vsftpd-2.0.5-12.el5' />
<patch name='openssl-devel-0.9.8e-7.el5' />
<patch name='sane-backends-1.0.18-5.el5' />
<patch name='libgnome-2.16.0-6.el5' />
<patch name='nautilus-extensions-2.16.2-7.el5' />
<patch name='librsvg2-2.16.1-1.el5' />
<patch name='xorg-x11-drv-mouse-1.1.1-1.1' />
<patch name='system-config-httpd-1.3.3.3-1.el5' />
<patch name='scim-doc-1.4.4-41.el5' />
<patch name='libgcj-devel-4.1.2-44.el5' />
<patch name='kdebase-3.5.4-19.el5' />
<patch name='scim-libs-1.4.4-41.el5' />
<patch name='dhcdbd-2.2-2.el5' />
<patch name='aex-inventory-7.0-6061' />
<patch name='krbafs-1.2.2-6' />
<patch name='perl-XML-Encoding-1.01-26' />
<patch name='pwlib-1.6.5-11' />
<patch name='kdemultimedia-3.3.1-2' />
<patch name='megaraid-v2.20.4.4-2dkms' />
<patch name='MQSeriesJava-6.0.1-0' />
<patch name='HelixPlayer-1.0.6-0.EL4.1' />
<patch name='gtk-engines-0.12-6.el4' />
<patch name='openmotif21-2.1.30-11.RHEL4.6' />
<patch name='IBM_db2icut81-8.1.3-136' />
<patch name='IBM_db2ca81-8.1.3-136' />
<patch name='pexp_x8664_c000-12.00.00.00-1' />
<patch name='cyrus-sasl-plain-2.1.22-4' />
<patch name='pam_passwdqc-1.0.2-1.2.2' />
<patch name='rdist-6.1.5-44' />
<patch name='pinfo-0.6.9-1.fc6' />
<patch name='libwnck-2.16.0-4.fc6' />
<patch name='libtermcap-devel-2.0.8-46.1' />
<patch name='indent-2.2.9-14.fc6' />
<patch name='webalizer-2.01_10-30.1' />
<patch name='sound-juicer-2.16.0-3.el5' />
<patch name='xorg-x11-drv-cirrus-1.1.0-2.fc6' />
<patch name='xorg-x11-drv-magictouch-1.0.0.5-2.1' />
<patch name='xorg-x11-drivers-7.1-4.1.el5' />
<patch name='gdk-pixbuf-0.22.0-25.el5' />
<patch name='bluez-hcidump-1.32-1' />
<patch name='perl-XML-Twig-3.26-1.fc6' />
<patch name='screen-4.0.3-1.el5' />
<patch name='kde-i18n-German-3.5.4-1' />
<patch name='termcap-5.5-1.20060701.1' />
<patch name='glibc-2.5-34' />
<patch name='readline-5.1-1.1' />
<patch name='nspr-4.7.3-2.el5' />
<patch name='binutils-2.17.50.0.6-9.el5' />
<patch name='iptables-1.3.5-4.el5' />
<patch name='mailx-8.1.1-44.2.2' />
<patch name='libvorbis-1.1.2-3.el5_1.2' />
<patch name='libusb-0.1.12-5.1' />
<patch name='libmng-1.0.9-5.1' />
<patch name='enscript-1.6.4-4.1.1.el5_2' />
<patch name='procmail-3.22-17.1' />
<patch name='libacl-2.2.39-3.el5' />
<patch name='aspell-0.60.3-7.1' />
<patch name='libXmu-1.0.2-5' />
<patch name='libXv-1.0.1-4.1' />
<patch name='libXevie-1.0.1-3.1' />
<patch name='libXxf86vm-1.0.1-3.1' />
<patch name='mesa-libGLU-6.5.1-7.7.el5' />
<patch name='tar-1.15.1-23.0.1.el5' />
<patch name='libXft-2.1.10-1.1' />
<patch name='python-elementtree-1.2.6-5' />
<patch name='device-mapper-event-1.02.28-2.el5' />
<patch name='pygobject2-2.12.1-5.el5' />
<patch name='hwdata-0.213.11-1.el5' />
<patch name='libXft-2.1.10-1.1' />
<patch name='passwd-0.73-1' />
<patch name='alsa-lib-1.0.17-1.el5' />
<patch name='libutempter-1.1.4-4.el5' />
<patch name='emacs-common-21.4-20.el5' />
<patch name='wpa_supplicant-0.5.10-8.el5' />
<patch name='cups-1.3.7-8.el5' />
<patch name='perl-DBI-1.52-2.el5' />
<patch name='libicu-3.6-5.11.1' />
<patch name='libacl-devel-2.2.39-3.el5' />
<patch name='apr-1.2.7-11' />
<patch name='squid-2.6.STABLE21-3.el5' />
<patch name='xml-common-0.6.3-18' />
<patch name='zenity-2.16.0-2.el5' />
<patch name='openssh-askpass-4.3p2-29.el5' />
<patch name='httpd-manual-2.2.3-22.el5' />
<patch name='dbus-glib-devel-0.73-8.el5' />
<patch name='vnc-server-4.1.2-14.el5' />
<patch name='libbonoboui-2.16.0-1.fc6' />
<patch name='gnome-utils-2.16.0-5.el5' />
<patch name='gnome-python2-2.16.0-1.fc6' />
<patch name='gnome-python2-applet-2.16.0-2.el5' />
<patch name='firstboot-1.4.27.7-1.el5' />
<patch name='dovecot-1.0.7-7.el5' />
<patch name='kdebase-3.5.4-19.el5' />
<patch name='isdn4k-utils-3.2-51.el5' />
<patch name='gimp-print-4.2.7-22.2.el5' />
<patch name='tcl-8.4.13-3.fc6' />
<patch name='aex-nsclt-7.0-8641' />
<patch name='system-config-mouse-1.2.9-1' />
<patch name='openjade-1.3.2-14' />
<patch name='imlib-1.9.13-23' />
<patch name='seamonkey-nspr-1.0.3-0.el4.1' />
<patch name='gaim-1.5.0-12.el4' />
<patch name='kdeaddons-3.3.1-2' />
<patch name='mysqlclient10-3.23.58-4.RHEL4.1' />
<patch name='ominstall-links-5.1.0-354' />
<patch name='bnx2-1.4.36b-5dkms' />
<patch name='IBM_db2icw81-8.1.3-136' />
<patch name='IBM_db2dc81-8.1.3-136' />
<patch name='tdicu-12.00.00.00-1' />
<patch name='cliv2_64-12.00.00.00-1' />
<patch name='libXfontcache-1.0.2-3.1' />
<patch name='nano-1.3.12-1.1' />
<patch name='gail-1.9.2-1.fc6' />
<patch name='readahead-1.3-7.el5' />
<patch name='boost-1.33.1-10.el5' />
<patch name='hesiod-devel-3.1.0-8' />
<patch name='ctags-5.6-1.1' />
<patch name='gnome-system-monitor-2.16.0-3.el5' />
<patch name='xorg-x11-drv-fpit-1.1.0-1.1' />
<patch name='xorg-x11-drv-aiptek-1.0.1-2' />
<patch name='xorg-x11-drv-calcomp-1.1.0-1.1' />
<patch name='compat-db-4.2.52-5.1' />
<patch name='compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-61' />
<patch name='statserial-1.1-38.2.2' />
<patch name='cyrus-sasl-md5-2.1.22-4' />
<patch name='zsh-4.2.6-1' />
<patch name='gnome-keyring-manager-2.16.0-3.el5' />
<patch name='xkeyboard-config-0.8-7.fc6' />
<patch name='popt-1.10.2.3-9.el5' />
<patch name='gawk-3.1.5-14.el5' />
<patch name='libjpeg-6b-37' />
<patch name='popt-1.10.2.3-9.el5' />
<patch name='ed-0.2-39.el5_2' />
<patch name='libfontenc-1.0.2-2.2.el5' />
<patch name='libvolume_id-095-14.19.el5' />
<patch name='libdrm-2.0.2-1.1' />
<patch name='aspell-0.60.3-7.1' />
<patch name='libiec61883-1.0.0-11.fc6' />
<patch name='cdrecord-2.01-10.7.el5' />
<patch name='libFS-1.0.0-3.1' />
<patch name='tcp_wrappers-7.6-40.6.el5' />
<patch name='libXext-1.0.1-2.1' />
<patch name='redhat-logos-4.9.16-1' />
<patch name='xorg-x11-xkb-utils-1.0.2-2.1' />
<patch name='libXfixes-4.0.1-2.1' />
<patch name='coreutils-5.97-19.el5' />
<patch name='newt-0.52.2-12.el5' />
<patch name='libgssapi-0.10-2' />
<patch name='MAKEDEV-3.23-1.2' />
<patch name='lockdev-1.0.1-10' />
<patch name='python-numeric-23.7-2.2.2' />
<patch name='fontconfig-2.4.1-7.el5' />
<patch name='libpcap-0.9.4-14.el5' />
<patch name='portmap-4.0-65.2.2.1' />
<patch name='dnsmasq-2.45-1.el5_2.1' />
<patch name='openssh-server-4.3p2-29.el5' />
<patch name='kernel-2.6.18-128.el5' />
<patch name='libnotify-0.4.2-6.el5' />
<patch name='redhat-lsb-3.1-12.3.EL' />
<patch name='libgomp-4.3.2-7.el5' />
<patch name='glibc-headers-2.5-34' />
<patch name='keyutils-libs-devel-1.2-1.el5' />
<patch name='gcc-gfortran-4.1.2-44.el5' />
<patch name='perl-DBD-MySQL-3.0007-2.el5' />
<patch name='gnome-doc-utils-0.8.0-2.fc6' />
<patch name='pygtk2-libglade-2.10.1-12.el5' />
<patch name='samba-3.0.33-3.7.el5' />
<patch name='system-config-language-1.1.18-2.el5' />
<patch name='bind-chroot-9.3.4-10.P1.el5' />
<patch name='xorg-x11-fonts-base-7.1-2.1.el5' />
<patch name='libbonoboui-2.16.0-1.fc6' />
<patch name='gthumb-2.7.8-8.el5' />
<patch name='nautilus-2.16.2-7.el5' />
<patch name='system-config-network-1.3.99.12-1.el5' />
<patch name='xorg-x11-drv-mutouch-1.1.0-3' />
<patch name='libobjc-4.1.2-44.el5' />
<patch name='rpm-build-4.4.2.3-9.el5' />
<patch name='pyparted-1.8.1-4.el5' />
<patch name='scim-anthy-1.2.0-6.el5' />
<patch name='aex-serverinventory-7.0-6022' />
<patch name='Omni-0.9.1-7.1' />
<patch name='Omni-foomatic-0.9.1-7.1' />
<patch name='pilot-link-0.11.8-8' />
<patch name='gnomemeeting-1.0.2-8' />
<patch name='w3c-libwww-5.4.0-10' />
<patch name='kdepim-3.3.1-2.1' />
<patch name='kdegraphics-3.3.1-3.9' />
<patch name='ipv6-1.1-1dkms' />
<patch name='xorg-x11-rhel4_radeon_dell_server-6.8.1-23.DELL.6.EL' />
<patch name='IBMJava2-AMD64-142-SDK-1.4.2-0.0' />
<patch name='elfutils-0.97.1-3' />
<patch name='openssl096b-0.9.6b-22.42' />
<patch name='IBM_db2secl81-8.1.3-136' />
<patch name='IBM_db2adts81-8.1.3-136' />
<patch name='IBM_db2xml81-8.1.3-136' />
<patch name='TeraGSS_redhatlinux-i386-06.02.00.00-1' />
<patch name='npaxsmod-01.05.00.00-1' />
<patch name='plod_x8664_c000-12.00.00.00-1' />
<patch name='fastexp-12.00.00.00-1' />
<patch name='rmt-0.4b41-2.fc6' />
<patch name='libXevie-1.0.1-3.1' />
<patch name='cdparanoia-alpha9.8-27.2' />
<patch name='fbset-2.1-22' />
<patch name='jwhois-3.2.3-8.el5' />
<patch name='libgtop2-2.14.4-3.el5' />
<patch name='netpbm-10.35-6.fc6' />
<patch name='dos2unix-3.1-27.1' />
<patch name='finger-0.17-32.2.1.1' />
<patch name='cyrus-sasl-2.1.22-4' />
<patch name='boost-1.33.1-10.el5' />
<patch name='libXvMC-1.0.2-2.1' />
<patch name='patchutils-0.2.31-2.2.2' />
<patch name='cscope-15.5-15.fc6.1' />
<patch name='libdbi-0.8.1-2.1' />
<patch name='system-config-rootpassword-1.1.9.1-1' />
<patch name='sendmail-cf-8.13.8-2.el5' />
<patch name='valgrind-3.2.1-6.el5' />
<patch name='libtool-1.5.22-6.1' />
<patch name='gnome-netstatus-2.12.0-5.el5' />
<patch name='eog-2.16.0.1-6.el5' />
<patch name='orca-1.0.0-5.el5' />
<patch name='file-roller-2.16.0-2.fc6' />
<patch name='xorg-x11-drv-penmount-1.1.0-2.1' />
<patch name='xorg-x11-drv-elographics-1.1.0-1.1' />
<patch name='xorg-x11-drv-joystick-1.1.0-1.1' />
<patch name='xorg-x11-drv-hyperpen-1.1.0-2' />
<patch name='gtk+-1.2.10-56.el5' />
<patch name='compat-gcc-34-g77-3.4.6-4' />
<patch name='aspell-de-0.50-11.2.2' />
<patch name='anthy-7900-4.el5' />
<patch name='man-pages-de-0.4-11' />
<patch name='xmlsec1-openssl-1.2.9-8.1' />
<patch name='gtkspell-2.0.11-2.1' />
<patch name='kdeutils-3.5.4-5.fc6' />
<patch name='perl-XML-Parser-2.34-6.1.2.2.1' />
<patch name='perl-XML-LibXML-1.58-5' />
<patch name='xchat-2.6.6-8.el5' />
<patch name='cyrus-sasl-md5-2.1.22-4' />
<patch name='unixODBC-kde-2.2.11-7.1' />
<patch name='nash-5.1.19.6-44' />
<patch name='emacs-leim-21.4-20.el5' />
<patch name='zlib-1.2.3-3' />
<patch name='bzip2-libs-1.0.3-4.el5_2' />
<patch name='ncurses-5.5-24.20060715' />
<patch name='libpng-1.2.10-7.1.el5_0.1' />
<patch name='libxml2-2.6.26-2.1.2.7' />
<patch name='tcp_wrappers-7.6-40.6.el5' />
<patch name='libpng-1.2.10-7.1.el5_0.1' />
<patch name='db4-4.3.29-9.fc6' />
<patch name='libvolume_id-095-14.19.el5' />
<patch name='patch-2.5.4-29.2.3.el5' />
<patch name='gzip-1.3.5-10.el5' />
<patch name='libICE-1.0.1-2.1' />
<patch name='slang-2.0.6-4.el5' />
<patch name='iputils-20020927-45.el5' />
<patch name='libXdmcp-1.0.1-2.1' />
<patch name='libIDL-0.8.7-1.fc6' />
<patch name='keyutils-libs-1.2-1.el5' />
<patch name='speex-1.0.5-4.el5_1.1' />
<patch name='mkisofs-2.01-10.7.el5' />
<patch name='acl-2.2.39-3.el5' />
<patch name='ttmkfdir-3.0.9-23.el5' />
<patch name='cdrdao-1.2.1-2' />
<patch name='libart_lgpl-2.3.17-4' />
<patch name='flac-1.1.2-28.el5_0.1' />
<patch name='audiofile-0.2.6-5' />
<patch name='gamin-0.1.7-8.el5' />
<patch name='redhat-menus-6.7.8-3.el5' />
<patch name='libXrandr-1.1.1-3.1' />
<patch name='libXxf86misc-1.0.1-3.1' />
<patch name='libXres-1.0.1-3.1' />
<patch name='perl-HTML-Parser-3.55-1.fc6' />
<patch name='xorg-x11-font-utils-7.1-2' />
<patch name='libXrandr-1.1.1-3.1' />
<patch name='libXpm-3.5.5-3' />
<patch name='cryptsetup-luks-1.0.3-4.el5' />
<patch name='e2fsprogs-libs-1.39-20.el5' />
<patch name='cairo-1.2.4-5.el5' />
<patch name='mesa-libGL-6.5.1-7.7.el5' />
<patch name='libuser-0.54.7-2.el5.5' />
<patch name='bind-libs-9.3.4-10.P1.el5' />
<patch name='yum-metadata-parser-1.1.2-2.el5' />
<patch name='qt-3.3.6-23.el5' />
<patch name='cryptsetup-luks-1.0.3-4.el5' />
<patch name='gphoto2-2.2.0-3.el5' />
<patch name='autofs-5.0.1-0.rc2.102' />
<patch name='fetchmail-6.3.6-1.1.el5' />
<patch name='Xaw3d-1.5E-10.1' />
<patch name='python-urlgrabber-3.1.0-5.el5' />
<patch name='cairo-1.2.4-5.el5' />
<patch name='GConf2-2.14.0-9.el5' />
<patch name='SysVinit-2.86-15.el5' />
<patch name='kbd-1.12-21.el5' />
<patch name='GConf2-2.14.0-9.el5' />
<patch name='samba-common-3.0.33-3.7.el5' />
<patch name='nss_ldap-253-17.el5' />
<patch name='mkinitrd-5.1.19.6-44' />
<patch name='prelink-0.4.0-2.el5' />
<patch name='rpm-libs-4.4.2.3-9.el5' />
<patch name='dbus-libs-1.1.2-12.el5' />
<patch name='dbus-1.1.2-12.el5' />
<patch name='avahi-0.6.16-1.el5' />
<patch name='NetworkManager-glib-0.7.0-3.el5' />
<patch name='kudzu-devel-1.2.57.1.21-1' />
<patch name='perl-BSD-Resource-1.28-1.fc6.1' />
<patch name='diffstat-1.41-1.2.3.el5' />
<patch name='slang-devel-2.0.6-4.el5' />
<patch name='libogg-devel-1.1.3-3.el5' />
<patch name='nss-devel-3.12.2.0-2.el5' />
<patch name='jpackage-utils-1.7.3-1jpp.2.el5' />
<patch name='elfutils-libelf-devel-0.137-3.el5' />
<patch name='mx-2.0.6-2.2.2' />
<patch name='xterm-215-8.el5' />
<patch name='kexec-tools-1.102pre-56.el5' />
<patch name='openjade-1.3.2-27' />
<patch name='libglade2-2.6.0-2' />
<patch name='postgresql-libs-8.1.11-1.el5_1.1' />
<patch name='php-cli-5.1.6-23.el5' />
<patch name='mysql-5.0.45-7.el5' />
<patch name='arts-1.5.4-1' />
<patch name='system-config-samba-1.2.41-3.el5' />
<patch name='bind-9.3.4-10.P1.el5' />
<patch name='avahi-glib-0.6.16-1.el5' />
<patch name='ghostscript-8.15.2-9.4.el5' />
<patch name='gnome-vfs2-2.16.2-4.el5' />
<patch name='libgnomeprint22-2.12.1-10.el5' />
<patch name='gnome-vfs2-2.16.2-4.el5' />
<patch name='gnome-panel-2.16.1-7.el5' />
</ospatches>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The row id are saved **separately** from the cells. So if you have `id` property in the `row` (`row.id`) you don't need to add the `id` column. So you can just remove `'id'` from the `colNames` and the corresponding `id` column in the `colModel`.

Moreover as I wrote you in the previous answer the usage of `addRowData` is much slowly as the usage of `data:filesystem` parameter of jqGrid. If you try to do this with 100 or 1000 rows you will see the difference very clear.

You can consider to use [sorttype:'int'](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acolmodel_options) for all column to make sorting of columns work correct. An additional property [formatter:'integer'](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3apredefined_formatter#predefined_format_types) can improve look of the large numbers.

**UPDATED**: I decide to clear more exactly the difference between the usage of additional hidden `id` column and having no `id` column at all. Let us you have the following row of data:

```
{id:5, total:10, free:20, used:30, percentage:40}
```

(it isn't important whether the values are strings like "20" or numbers like `20`). If you include the property `hidden:true` in the definition of the `id` column the row of the data in the grid will looks in the simplified form as

```
<tr id="5"><td style="display:none">5</td><td>10</td><td>20</td><td>30</td><td>40</td></tr>
```

if you just remove the `id` column the row will look like

```
<tr id="5"><td>10</td><td>20</td><td>30</td><td>40</td></tr>
```

**The jqGrid uses only the id attribute of `tr` and never use information from the additional hidden `id` column**. So is you just remove unneeded `id` column from the `colModel` you would reduce the memory usage of the grid and improve a little the performance of the page.

Comment: @Oleg: Thanks, so i will just remove `row.id=i++;` and entries from `colNames` and `colModel`

Comment: @Ricky: If you just assign `row.id=i++;` you can remove is too because the default behavior of jqGrid if no `id` is defined is to assign as ids the integers 1,2,3... If you have more as one grid per page or use integer ids already **you should do has line like `row.id='myidprefix'+i++;` with different prefix per grid**. If you don't assign any `id` properties and have at least two jqGrids you will have id duplicates which is not allowed in HTML and many things (like row selection) in jqGrid will work incorrectly. So better **no `id` column in `colModel`, but assigning `id` properties of data**

Comment: @Oleg: at any time I am having only 1 jqGrid in a page. Also can you tell me usage for `data:filesystem` coz i am experiencing slowness, while getting data into grid. Can you edit my answer for `data:filesystem` to reflect? Thanks

Comment: @Ricky: The usage of `data:filesystem` together with `gridview: true` should get you the best performance. If you do has bad performance you should post test XML data which can be used to reproduce the bad performance.

Comment: @Oleg: I posted my XML data in which I am having bad performance with `ospatches` data (see my question part). How can i use `data:ospatches` in this context? can you edit my question to reflect the changes?

Comment: @Oleg: I want to know how should i use `data:ospatches` shall i remove `for(var i=0;i<ospatches.length;i++)
        jQuery("#list1").jqGrid('addRowData',i+1,ospatches[i]);` and use `jQuery("#list1").jqGrid('data','ospatches');`? also i have added `gridview: true` This does not make it fast. I am probably going wrong somewhere